# Problem with phpword converting docx to html

Tags: php, phpword

I'm attempting to convert a DOCX document to HTML using the PHPWord library. However, during the conversion process, it doesn't include images, backgrounds, headers, or footers. It only retains tables and plain text without any styling.
Below my code:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
$phpWord = IOFactory::load('test1.docx', 'Word2007');
$htmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$htmlWriter->save('test.html');
```

please, any idea on how to fix this?